# Why is the accuracy of my Sequential Model stuck at 0.2155?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

First things first, I'm new to Machine Learning, so please bear with my lack of knowledge. I'm trying to create an Image classfier using the Sequential Model, to detect the following items-
[image]

I've prepared the dataset for each of these, where each image is (200,200) in dimensions, and the total number images is about 1200.

The problem is that, when I train it, the accuracy gets stuck at 0.2155-

[image]

I have absolutely no clue where I've went wrong, so can sommeone help me with this, and point out where I've went wrong? Here's the full code-

```
import numpy as np
import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import os
import cv2

X_train=[]
y_train=[]
size= 200

#preprocessing 
imagedir= "preprocessed"
pathdir= os.path.join("Images",imagedir)
for image_name in os.listdir("preprocessed/"):

    image_path= os.path.join("preprocessed",image_name)
    image= cv2.imread(image_path)
    X_train.append(image)
    if image_name.startswith("pen"):
        y_train.append(0)
    elif image_name.startswith("spoon"):
        y_train.append(1)
    elif image_name.startswith("ceiling_fan"):
        y_train.append(2)
    elif image_name.startswith("clock"):
        y_train.append(3)
    elif image_name.startswith("paper_airplane"):
        y_train.append(4)
    elif image_name.startswith("tomato"):
        y_train.append(5)
    elif image_name.startswith("banana"):
        y_train.append(6)
    elif image_name.startswith("leaf"):
        y_train.append(7)
    elif image_name.startswith("coin"):
        y_train.append(8)
    elif image_name.startswith("phone"):
        y_train.append(9)

    
X_train= np.array(X_train)
y_train= np.array(y_train)

X_train= X_train/255



test_size= 30

X_train= X_train[0:-test_size]
y_train= y_train[0:-test_size]

X_test= X_train[-test_size:-1]
y_test= y_train[-test_size:-1]

print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape)
print(y_train.shape, y_test.shape)

X_train_array= X_train.reshape(len(X_train), (size**2)*3)
X_test_array= X_test.reshape(len(X_test), (size**2)*3)

print(X_train_array.shape)

model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(10, input_shape=((size**2)*3,), activation='sigmoid')])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train_array, y_train, epochs=100)

y_predict_test=model.predict(X_test_array)

y_predict_test_labels=[]

for i in y_predict_test:
    y_predict_test_labels.append(np.argmax(i))

model.save("Model.h5")
```

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: last layer activation and loss function in compile - look into this.

Comment: also I believe you are confused what "sequential" is. It really is *not* a model, and it literally does nothing in your case, you could just remove it and your code would be equivalent (as in just use Dense)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding more dense layers in your model for better accuracy and also change the activation function of final dense layer to `'softmax'` as there is multi classes(num_classes=10) in your model.

```
model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(32, input_shape=((size**2)*3,), activation='relu')
                          keras.layers.Dense(64,  activation='relu')
                          keras.layers.Dense(32,  activation='relu')
                          keras.layers.Dense(10,  activation='softmax')])
```